# What's the difference between One::one() vs 1

Tags: rust

What is the difference between `One::one()` and just the number `1`? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`One::one()` is intended to be used in generic code where we do not know what is the exact type of the [numerical value](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.14/num_traits/identities/trait.One.html#foreign-impls).

It could be `1_i32`, `1.0`, `1_u8`... depending on the exact type the `One` trait is bound to.

---

Thanks to the useful comments below, here is a minimal example to try to illustrate better (although it's late).

Trying to initialise some variables with `1` works if they are considered as integers (`a` and `c` here).
On the other hand, this does not work for a real (`b` here); `1.0` must be used instead.

When it comes to our own non-primtive type (`Thing` here), the `One` trait helps providing a value considered as `1` (note that the `Mul` trait must be implemented on this type too).

The `One` trait becomes really useful in a generic function in which the exact type is not already known when we need the `1` value (like `mul_one()` here).

```rust
use num_traits::One;
use std::ops::Mul;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Thing {
    member: String,
}

// Mul<Self, Output = Self> is required for One
impl Mul for Thing {
    type Output = Self;
    fn mul(
        self,
        rhs: Self,
    ) -> Self {
        Self {
            member: self.member + "×" + &rhs.member,
        }
    }
}

impl One for Thing {
    fn one() -> Self {
        Self {
            member: "one".to_owned(),
        }
    }
}

fn mul_one<T: One>(arg: T) -> T {
    // arg * 1 // error: expected type parameter `T`, found integer
    arg * T::one()
}

fn main() {
    let a: i32 = 1;
    // let b: f64 = 1; // error: expected `f64`, found integer
    let b: f64 = 1.0;
    let c: u8 = 1;
    let d = Thing::one();
    println!("{:?} {:?} {:?} {:?}", a, b, c, d);
    let e = mul_one(a);
    let f = mul_one(b);
    let g = mul_one(c);
    let h = mul_one(d);
    println!("{:?} {:?} {:?} {:?}", e, f, g, h);
}

/*
1 1.0 1 Thing { member: "one" }
1 1.0 1 Thing { member: "one×one" }
*/
```

Comment: To complement this answer: the literal `1` will work for any of the types mentioned, but only if the concrete type is known at use-site. However because there is no literals-related trait, there is no way to use `1` for a generic type, no matter what trait bounds you set. That is, you can't write any `fn foo<T>() -> T where T: ??? { 1 }` which will compile, no matter what you replace `???` with.

Comment: Further, `One` can be implemented for non-primitive types that have a "oneness" about them. For example complex numbers or objects from linear algebra.